# Location client sometimes returns 0.0

Tags: android, gps, google-play-services

Every 2 minutes i create new location client and location request it works 20 second after that i get coordinates from location. 
When I drive everything well, but when I stop location returns 0.0.
In my app I use Google Play Services.

Answer (score 1):

This is usually a programming error on your side. (or in an API you use)
Check if the location is valid (accuracy > 0, etc.)

However my experience is, it is better to always ignore a (0.0/0.0) location.
Such a location is never the result of a correct position!
(Except in unit tests)